# Magento Configurable Product Image too Large

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, image

I wanted to create configurable products in my shop.
As i did that and was ready, i found out that my image is way too big.

I mean the whole layout is strange and does not look like the one for simple products.

Iam using Magento 1.9.0.1 with a custom default template.

[image: Picture]

I just don't know how to edit this layout.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understand your question(! :-)) correctly.

You want your image smaller?

Magento has a service for that: `\Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image`

You can see here `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml:40` how to use it (lines from EE 1.14.2)

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')
```

But you can do a lot more, like resizing:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(265)
```

Just have a look in the class or google what your options are. If you only want to resize the image, `resize` is your friend.